# Font-awesome class not switching based on condition in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I just have an element that opens and closes on click

```
<div class="folderItemHeader" :class="{ bold: isFolder }" @click="toggleChild(item)" :title="item.name">
          <span v-if="isFolder" style="color: Tomato;">
            <!-- LINE 1 <i :class="['fas', item.show ? 'fa-folder-open' : 'fa-folder']" :key="item.show"></i>                -->
            <i class="fas fa-folder-open" v-if="item.show"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-folder" v-if="!item.show"></i>
          </span>
          {{ item.name }} {{ item.show }}
</div>
```

The first time it renders properly
But when I click anything the first time nothing happens, (it should show the other icon)
When I click again, it adds a new element

When I uncomment LINE1, it shows all icons in the correct format (first one is open, other children are closed initially), but after that nothing updates.

Note that the true and false value for item.show does actually update

Just to add more information, issue is not with Vue.js, because using my custom class instead of font-awesome works fine

```
<span v-if="isFolder" style="color: Tomato;">
    <i :class="[item.show ? 'showClass' : 'dontShowClass']">My Data</i>
</span>
```

I import all in my index.js.

```
// "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0"
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands';
```

Do I need to update my webpack.js?

[image]

Comment: can you make an example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Issue is not with vue.js, because I can add a normal class and it toggles. It's only with font awesome that it fails. I am thinking version conflicts? Updated versions.

Comment: You can change fontawesome icon classes for 'i' tag manually in browser dev tools and check if an icon is changed accordingly.

Comment: I tried doint that. The classes were loading. It wasn't reactive. I used this blog to use vue-fontwaesome to load instead. I think this handled the reactivity.
https://blog.logrocket.com/full-guide-to-using-font-awesome-icons-in-vue-js-apps-5574c74d9b2d/

Comment: Are you sure that all your items are reactive? And all of them had the 'show' prop before they became reactive?

Comment: Yes. All are reactive. I used the exact same show properties to add custom class instead of font-awesome class, and they worked properly.